# Can one inhibit eval-when-compile?

Tags: byte-compilation

There is an `eval-when-compile` macro but, AFAICT, no `eval-when-not-compiling` or `load-time-only`, that would be very convenient for me now. Do you know any generic workaround?

Why do I need this: I have a package with `(eval-when-compile (load "other-package"))` and, in this other package, some initialisation code that is for load time only. That the code is for load time only is understood implicitly when the `other-package` itself is compiled, but not when it is loaded as part of compiling something else.

Comment: When you compile the package, you **load** `other-package`, therefore it **is** load time for `other-package`. You could try checking if byte compilation is in progress like `cl--compiling-file` does perhaps.

Comment: An alternative to calling `cl--compiling-file` is to inspect the value of `(bound-and-true-p  byte-compile-current-file)`, which is only set during byte-compilation.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT:

The comment of [npostavs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/5296/npostavs) is true. When you `load` `"other-package"` during byte compilation the test result on byte-compilation in `"other-package"` is negative.

You need to remember in the original package that you are byte-compiling.
You can do that by let-binding:

A minimal example:

Content of the original package:

```el
(eval-when-compile
  (let ((other-package-loading-for-compilation t))
    (load "other-package")))
```

Content of `"other-package"`:

```el
(unless (bound-and-true-p other-package-loading-for-compilation)
  (message "For initialization only"))
```

---

OLD Answer:

I assume that you have already compiled `other-package`.
In that case

`(cl-eval-when (load) ...)`

in `other-package` works.

The doc-string of `cl-eval-when`:

> (cl-eval-when (WHEN...) BODY...)
>
> Control when BODY is evaluated.
>
> If ‘compile’ is in WHEN, BODY is evaluated when compiled at top-level.
>
> If ‘load’ is in WHEN, BODY is evaluated when loaded after top-level compile.
>
> If ‘eval’ is in WHEN, BODY is evaluated when interpreted or at non-top-level.

From my perspective the `load` case description is a bit misleading. It means that BODY is evaluated when the byte-compiled library is loaded -- **not** only directly after byte-compilation.

You can also combine the cases.
If you want BODY to be evaluated also when the source file is loaded you can use

`(cl-eval-when (eval load) ...)`

Comment: @phils Thanks for the correction of my lapse.

Comment: In my tests, this makes no difference to the problem described by phs.

Comment: @Stefan I am afraid I didn't understand the OP's question in full. Now I edited my answer to address the OP's problem. Since some folks found the answer to be useful I keep the old content.

Comment: thanks for the update.  Note that in your updated solution, the `(eval-when (load eval)` is just redundant (a top-level expression of the form `(unless ...)` will not be evaluated by the compiler anyway).  Also you might like to use `bound-and-true-p` to make sure the var is actually bound to a non-nil value.

Comment: @Stefan I first thought of just using `(let (other-package-loading-for-compilation) (load "other-package"))` but now I changed to your version with `bound-and-true-p`. It is more clear. Okay, the doc says the other forms are batched together and the compiled code will be executed when the file is read. Therefore, the `eval-when` is redundant. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really have a solution for that problem, sadly.  If you have control of `other-package`, the recommended way to solve those problems is to move the load-time only code into a function, because loading a package should always be "harmless" (Emacs occasionally loads Elisp files without a very strong reason, e.g. just to find out if a particular function is defined in it).

I.e. in `other-package` you change

```
(some-undesirable-load-time-code)
```

into

```
;;;###autoload
(defun other-package-initialize ()
  (some-undesirable-load-time-code))
```

and then the users of `other-package` will need to change

```
(require 'other-package)
```

into

```
(other-package-initialize)
```

when they want the initialization rather than just loading the file.